# Imaginary and real part of some complex function

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be some probability measure and 
$$g(t) = \log \int\exp(itx)\mu(dx) $$

How to see, that

1. $\mathcal{Im}(g)$ is odd
   and
2. that $\mathcal{Re}(g)\leq 0 \,\,\forall\ t\in\mathbb{R}$

Finally i want to show that it holds

$$f(0) := g(0) - \frac{1}{2}\int_{-1}^1g(t)dt \geq 0$$

Which should be easy to proof, if (1) and (2) is correct, but I do not really see it. Can anybody help?

---

Let $$ z:= \int\exp(itx)\mu(dx)$$ for some fixed $t$.
Due to $\log(z) = \ln(|{z}|) + i\arg{z}$ we have that $\mathcal{Im}(g)$ is odd and because $\mu$ is a probability measure we have $|z|\leq 1$, so finally $\mathcal{Re}(g)\leq0$ Now $g(0) = 0$ so $f(0) \ge0$

Comment: Do you know that the imaginary part of the logarithm of a complex number $z$ is the argument of $z$ (unique only modulo $2\pi$) and the real part is the (real) logarithm of $|z|$?

Comment: I made an edit to my question. Is that correct?

Comment: Looks good, but lacking some detail.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, that I now got the correct idea. If the idea is correct, I am now able to work out this in detail on my own, I think. Thanks a lot for the hint / help. :)